# What is $H^{p,p}(X,\mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: hodge-theory

**Edited for presentation.**

How to define it with words or/and quantifiers?

Been struggling with a too big number of informations now, for hours.

$p\in \mathbb{N}$.

X is a $C^{\infty}$-manifold.